# CSS color transition behavior for images with transparent backgrounds

Tags: html, image, css, css-transitions

I've noticed an unanticipated effect of using CSS color transitions on an image with a transparent background. Here's an example:

```css
:root {
  --size: 4em;
  --duration: 5s;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  background: slategray;
  color: white;
}
.main-menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
}
.main-menu *:hover {
  background: skyblue;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 5s;
  transition-duration: var(--duration);
}
.image-div {
  float: right;
  padding: calc(var(--size) / 2);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 5s;
  transition-duration: var(--duration);
}
.image {
  max-width: var(--size);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-menu">
  <div class="image-div">
    <img class="image" src="https://s4.postimg.org/5zy6kjqcd/maximize.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

To summarize, the issue is this. If you hover over the *image-div* div's padding, the background color of this div and the contained *image* div execute the color transition at the same rate, as expected. However, if you hover over the *image* div, its color appears to transition slightly faster than the *image-div* div's color.

Given the fact that I was able to reproduce this exact behavior on Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Edge, I get the feeling that this is expected behavior, but I would like to understand why it is happening.

Comment: I posted the source code to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ot2oLfk/4/) if you'd like to play around with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you *hover* over the `img` *two* hover events are triggered - one on the `img` and one on its parent `image-div` when you use `*` in `.main-menu *:hover` selector:

Instead use the hover *only* on the `image-div` as below:

```
.main-menu .image-div:hover {
  background: skyblue;
}
```

and now the *difference* in `transition` will not be there - see demo below:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  background: slategray;
  color: white;
}
.main-menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
}
.main-menu .image-div:hover {
  background: skyblue;
}
.image-div {
  float: right;
  padding: calc(4em / 2);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 5s;
  transition-duration: 5s;
}
.image {
  max-width: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-menu">
  <div class="image-div">
    <img class="image" src="https://s4.postimg.org/5zy6kjqcd/maximize.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks kukkuz, I was just playing with that when I saw your reply. Excellent explanation!

Answer (score 1):

> Given the fact that I was able to reproduce this exact behavior on
>   Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Edge, I get the feeling that this is
>   expected behavior, but I would like to understand why it is happening.

The reason this happens is because the `img` transition picks up the `image-div` transitioned color, hence get lighter faster.

Simply put, the `image-div` goes from a solid black, while the `img` goes from black that turns into sky blue.

Additionally, since you move the mouse over the `image-div` before it gets to the `img`, the transition starts before, though the delay is based on how fast you move the mouse to the `img`

Comment: That's a great explanantion of how the transitions are applied. Thanks!